# Using PSExec to run a remote batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, psexec

Have been tasked with trying to run a CMD .bat script via psexec so that it can be ran on remote machines as system. The plan being to then schedule this to run every X amount of days, is this something that's possible?

Comment: Yes, is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible (assuming you mean SysInternals 'PSExec'), but might not be liked under the guise of Security.  There may be other more supported/allowable ways of achieving what you want - e.g. PowerShell (or even DSC if applicable).

But then it might be better/more secure, to set-up a local scheduled 'Windows Task' instead.